# Use Regex to validate a String and parse it into 2 groups

Tags: c#, regex

I am receiving a string which can be:

```
"+name" > + followed only by Alphanumeric characters
"-Age18" > - followed only by Alphanumeric characters
```

Notes:
1. The first character after +/- cannot be a number.
2. Spaces or any special characters (.,; ...) are not allowed.

I could use Substring to get the two parts of the String.

But how can I use Regex to validate the string and parse it into 2 groups?

I think Regex might be a better option, not?

**Update**:

I did tried Regex as follows:

```
String pattern = @"^[?<Direction>+|-]\[?<Value>A-Za-z0-9]$";

Match match = Regex.Match(value, pattern);

if (match.Success) {
  String direction = match.Groups["Direction"];
  String value = match.Groups["Value"];
}
```

But I didn't get the expected result so I think the problem is with my Regex?

Comment: Tried anything yet? "*Better option*" under which criteria?

Comment: @ardila Yes, I did ... I just added an update with what I tried. How would you validate if the string has only Alphanumeric without Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first group is the +/- and the second group is the rest then you can use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/gZ6uH2/1):

```
^([+-])([A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]*)$
```

And access the groups with indices `1` and `2`, like this:

```
String pattern = @"^([+-])([A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]*)$";

Match match = Regex.Match(value, pattern);

if (match.Success) {
  String direction = match.Groups[1];
  String value = match.Groups[2];
}
```

---

If you must name your groups, then [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/gZ6uH2/2):

```
^(?<Direction>[+-])(?<Value>[A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]*)$
```

Comment: how could I name the groups on your Regex instead of using the indexes? As I have on my question ...

Answer (score 1):

Without changing your code, this regex should work as expected :

```
String pattern = @"^(?<Direction>[+-])(?<Value>[A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]*)$";

Match match = Regex.Match(value, pattern);

if (match.Success) {
  String direction = match.Groups["Direction"];
  String value = match.Groups["Value"];
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/uT5eW0/1

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will match both parts of the string:

```
(?<Direction>[+-])(?<Value>[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)
```

Comment: Which type of groups is expected. I have assumed: First group: ([+-]), second group: ([A-Za-z0-9]+)

Comment: I added an update to my question with what I tried to get the groups. But I don't get what I expect. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Regexes are a good way. The simplest method is probably to define your regexes as Strings, and then use the static method in the Pattern class to test for a match.

```
String group1 = "[+][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*";
String group2 = "[-][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*";
String str = "-Age18";
if(Pattern.matches(group1, str)){
    // Group 1
    System.out.println("Group 1");
} else if(Pattern.matches(group2, str)){
    // Group 2
    System.out.println("Group 2");
} else{
    // Neither
    System.out.println("Neither");
}
```

Here, -Age18 will fall into Group 2

**Edit:** This was assuming just the validation parts. musefan's answer is much better for obtaining the values